# Dynamically or button click Search specific tab in tab control in c#

Tags: c#

i making some application for my office and in this application there are so many tabs (more than 50) i want to search tabs using textbox ,if its possible can someone kind enough to show how can i search dynamically instead clicking a search button

this is my code that i tried

```
     private void button62_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (secondtabcontainer.TabPages.ContainsKey.Equals("chattextbox"))
           secondtabcontainer.SelectedTab = secondtabcontainer.TabPages["tabPage17"];

   }

   private void textBox55_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       string chattextbox;
       chattextbox = textBox55.Text;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `TextChanged` event:

```
private void textBox55_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    string sTabName = textBox55.Text;

    foreach (TabPage tab in secondtabcontainer.TabPages) 
    {
        if (sTabName.Equals(tab.Name)) 
        {
            secondtabcontainer.SelectedTab = tab;
            break;
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: thanks nisar i tried it but it doesn't work.it leaves ContainsKey part is underlined as a error :(

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain a dictionary (`Dictionary<string, string>`) containing "Tab Display Name-TabID" pairs:

```
Dictionary<string, string> tabs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// sample entries
tabs.Add("First Tab", "tab1");
tabs.Add("Second Tab", "tab2");
// ...
tabs.Add("chattextbox", "tab17");
```

Then add the tabs to the `Items` collection on a new `ComboBox` control.

Add your code to the `SelectedValueChanged' event handler attached to the`ComboBox`.

```
// `TabsList` is a new control that make the tabs searchable.
protected void TabsList_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TabsList.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        var tabid = tabs[TabsList.SelectedText];
        secondtabcontainer.SelectedTab = secondtabcontainer.TabPages[tablid];
    }
}
```

This should allow you to type-ahead the name of a tab and automatically switch once you've made you selection.

Comment: could you kind enough to explain where should i put these line of codes :( i tried with my button control and new combobox but it always giving me a error. thanks

Comment: dear sir i got a working method and i managed to do it but without dynamic search , and i'll try your solution too . thank you very much  for helping me :)